# OSX Change Sublime Text 3 App Icon

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

I can't seem to change the icon of Sublime Text 3 like I did with 2. When I drag the image to the preview window, Sublime opens the image instead of the icon being replaced. Any ideas how to make this happen?

Comment: Is that related to programmation? Or is it just about customization?

Comment: Same as every other icon on OS X, [read this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153176/changing-sublime-text-3-icon-in-dock-on-yosemite)

Comment: Oops, I was dragging it to the wrong place, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Drag the desired to the top left image in the info, not the preview image.